# Weak derivative Gronwall’s inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-derivatives

I was wondering whether anyone knows about the existence of a Gronwall’s inequality for the weak derivative. Thanks.

Comment: There are Gronwall inequalities in integral form, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality#Integral_form_with_locally_finite_measures